# Get the id of an element at the particular position on screen

Tags: android

I am a beginner to android . So please help me.

Could some one please tell me how to get the id of an element in the screen at a particular point.

For ex: Let the display resolution be 480x800. And the display is filled with 2D array of buttons.

So how to get the id of the button that is present in the position 200,300.

Please help me.

#### NOTE

Size of the screen is given in pixel

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer you are looking for, but I'm pretty convinced that you should **not do** this.

The thing you are trying to do can be very errorprone, as there are many different screen sizes. The Android layout system is thought to handle any phone so it uses IDs to identify views instead of their exact position, which can vary.

Can you explain further, what are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: I got no problem with that , i have designed the logic such that it works for all the screen resolutions . I am working on a game , that makes me to track for components using pixels . So please help . Thanks

Comment: If the thing you are doing cannot be achieved as `onTouch` or `onClick` events, my idea is to iterate over Views which can be this components and look at their [LocationOnScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]))

Comment: Is there any function that returns the id of an element when the screen position is specified ? Thanks . Reply soon